# How to write a swift function that returns one of three types?

Tags: swift, types

I have three view controllers, `WebkitViewController`, and then two other view controllers `WebkitViewControllerA`, and `WebkitViewControllerB` that both extend `WebkitViewController`. I am having trouble writing a generic function that will look at the segue destination's view controller and tell me which of the three types it is. Is there a better way to do this?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.destination is WebKitViewController && sender is UIButton {
            let viewControllerType = {
                if segue.destination is WebKitViewControllerA {
                    WebKitViewControllerA.self
                } else if segue.destination is WebKitViewControllerB {
                    WebKitViewControllerB.self
                } else {
                    WebKitViewController.self
                }
            }()

            let button = sender as? UIButton
            let vc = segue.destination as? viewControllerType
            vc?.foo = "ho ho ho"
        }

    }

}
```

I also tried something like the following:

```
    var vc: WHAT_TYPE_TO_PUT_HERE?
    if segue.destination is CustomViewController {
        vc = segue.destination as? CustomViewController
    } else if segue.destination is WebKitBelowFoldViewController {
        vc = segue.destination as? WebKitBelowFoldViewController
    } else {
       vc = segue.destination as? WebKitViewController
    }
```

but I don't know what type I could give vc that type checker would be satisfied.

Comment: Aren't the identifiers of the segues unique so it would be easier to check the identifier?

Comment: @vadian If you're going to rely on the type (via `as?`) in order to assign some property, then you might as well rely on the type rather than also requiring an identifier.

Comment: Is there a relationship between the three VC classes? Are `WebKitViewControllerA` and `WebKitViewControllerB` subclasses of `WebKitViewController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these are all subclasses of WebkitViewController, `vc` would be WebkitViewController. Also, there should be no reason to check each type given the code you've shown here. All you should require is:

```
if let vc = segue.destination as? WebKitViewController {
    vc.foo = "ho ho ho"
}
```

Comment: wow thanks so much - I was making this needlessly complicated!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to fiddle with concrete types, create a protocol that all three VCs conform to.

It looks like the thing that's common among these three VCs is that all of them have a `foo` property, so we can create a protocol like so:

```
protocol HasFoo { // you should give this a better name base on your actual situation
    var foo: String! { get set } // remember to match the type of the foo property
}
```

And then conform the three VCs to it:

```
extension WebKitViewController : HasFoo {

}

extension WebKitViewControllerA : HasFoo {

}

extension WebKitViewControllerB : HasFoo {

}
```

Now you can simply do this in `prepareForSegue`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = sender.destination as? HasFoo {
        vc.foo = "ho ho ho"
    }
}
```